# How to load a configuration file in an ember.js project?

Tags: ember.js, configuration

I am working on a ember.js based product, that needs to load some configurations from a file, that is controlled by customers. Are there any best practices? So far, I haven't found any solution for this by using Google and co. May be you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON`/`$.ajax`.  Ember itself doesn't have any built in communication library.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return $.getJSON('/configuration');
  }
})

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['green', 'red', 'blue']
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:'application',
  isCool: Em.computed.alias('controllers.application.cool')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/817/edit